# ¿Cómo puedo generar un archivo geojson por cada consulta hecha a través de webscrapping?

Tags: python, json, geojson

Tengo un csv en el cual almaceno todas las url's a las que lanzo la consulta a través de beautiful soup de python. La consulta la hago através del siguiente script:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL_filename = 'ejemplo.csv'
URL_column_name = "url"
data = pd.read_csv(URL_filename,encoding='utf8')
weblink = (data[URL_column_name]).tolist()

i=0
while i<len(weblink):   
page = requests.get(weblink[i])
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
print (soup)

 i+=1
```

El script funciona y me arroja un resutado como este en formato geojson (un resultado similar para cada url):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "place_id": 110103318,
        "osm_type": "way",
        "osm_id": 149914077,
        "place_rank": 26,
        "category": "highway",
        "type": "residential",
        "importance": 0.1,
        "addresstype": "road",
        "name": "Calle Julio García",
        "display_name": "Calle Julio García, Circunvalación Oblatos, Guadalajara, Jalisco, 44720, México",
        "address": {
            "road": "Calle Julio García",
            "suburb": "Circunvalación Oblatos",
            "city": "Guadalajara",
            "county": "Guadalajara",
            "state": "Jalisco",
            "postcode": "44720",
            "country": "México",
            "country_code": "mx"
        }
    },
    "bbox": [-103.2838528, 20.6960196, -103.2835124, 20.6987892],
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-103.283776174626, 20.6966302195429]
    }
}]
}
```

Lo que quiero ahora es escribir un archivo con extensión geojson y con nombre seriado (por ejemplo "resultado1, resultado2, resultado3... resultado n) para cada resultado arrojado por el script. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Hola Jc Cabrera ¿Podrías compartir uno de los links? Es para reproducir el código. En principio creo que puedes prescindir de BS.

Comment: Claro! este es una de las URL: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=geojson&lat=20.6543147771&lon=-103.292783298

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo, usa un ciclo `for` para iterar en vez de un ciclo `while`, es más simple, legible y eficiente.

Por otro lado, no necesitas hacer uso de BS en principio, ya recibes un JSON directamente. Podrías guardarlo directamente en un archivo, aunque es mas seguro y te permite por ejemplo identar el JSON o escapar caracteres no ASCCI si lo parseas aun objeto Python (diccionario) previamente. `requets` ya dispone de un método `json()` para hacer esto.

Generar el nombre de cada archivo lo puedes hacer mediante formato de cadenas simplemente usando el índice, o incluso algún dato del GEOJASON si lo deseas.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests


URL_filename = 'ejemplo.csv'
URL_column_name = "url"

data = pd.read_csv(URL_filename, encoding='utf8')
for index, link in enumerate(data[URL_column_name]):
    data = requests.get(link).json()
    with open(f"resultado{index}.geojson", "w", encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Si no necesitas para otra cosa el DataFrame te recomiendo usar el módulo `json` de Python en su lugar, así te evitas crear el DataFrame en memoria con la sobrecarga que esto tiene.

```
import csv
import json
import requests


URL_filename = 'ejemplo.csv'
URL_column_name = "url"

with open(URL_filename) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for index, row in enumerate(reader):
        data = requests.get(row[URL_column_name]).json()
        with open(f"resultado{index}.geojson", "w", encoding='utf8') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

El contenido de archivo es  algo así:

> ```
> {
>     "type": "FeatureCollection",
>     "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
>     "features": [
>         {
>             "type": "Feature",
>             "properties": {
>                 "place_id": 264396886,
>                 "osm_type": "way",
>                 "osm_id": 693068333,
>                 "place_rank": 26,
>                 "category": "highway",
>                 "type": "residential",
>                 "importance": 0.1,
>                 "addresstype": "road",
>                 "name": null,
>                 "display_name": "Hermosa Provincia, Circunvalación Oblatos, Guadalajara, Jalisco, 44810, México",
>                 "address": {
>                     "neighbourhood": "Hermosa Provincia",
>                     "suburb": "Circunvalación Oblatos",
>                     "city": "Guadalajara",
>                     "county": "Guadalajara",
>                     "state": "Jalisco",
>                     "postcode": "44810",
>                     "country": "México",
>                     "country_code": "mx"
>                 }
>             },
>             "bbox": [
>                 -103.292706,
>                 20.6542394,
>                 -103.2924593,
>                 20.6542748
>             ],
>             "geometry": {
>                 "type": "Point",
>                 "coordinates": [
>                     -103.292706,
>                     20.6542748
>                 ]
>             }
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

Los archivos se nombran como `resutado<n>.geojason`, dónde `<n>` es el índice de cada fila, empezando en 0 (`resultado0.geojson`, `resultado1.geojason`, etc). Si usas Python < 3.6 debes hacer `"resultado{}.geojson".format(index)` en vez de `f"resultado{index}.geojson"`.

Comment: Genial! Eso si funcionó! Gracias!

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu ayuda! Si pudiera invitarte unas cervezas, ya mismo lo haría! Pero creo estamos lejos

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error: "simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) " Sabes que se puede deber??

Comment: Ya vi por qué el error. La API a la que está relacionada la url, tienen un límite de consultas, cuando lo sobrepaso ahi es cuando me arroja el error